# Problema com escopo de variável no loop foreach - NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Estou tentando retornar para a view ejs `home/index` o vetor de objetos `objArray`, porém ao sair do loop forEach e fazer todo tratamento dos dados que estou recebendo do banco o `objArray` retorna vazio.

Segue abaixo o código

```js
const model = require('../../models/home');

module.exports.index = async (app, req, res) => {
    let obj = {
        id_gt: 0,
        id_membro: 0,
        nome: '',
        escola: '',
        presenca: 0,
    };

    let objArray = [];

    let membros = await model.getMembro();

    membros.forEach(async membro => {
        let  presenca = await model.getPresenca(membro.id_membro);
        obj = {...membro, presenca: geraPresenca(presenca)}
        objArray = [...objArray, obj];
        //#1 console.log(objArray) retorna todo o vetor durante o loop
    });

    console.log(objArray); //#2 retorna = []
    res.render('home/index', {objArray});
}
```

Como destaquei no código, em ***#1*** o código retorna todos os objetos dentro do array, porém em ***#2***, ao sair do laço, o log da função retorna um vetor vazio.

Como posso fazer com que eu consiga "enxergar" essas alterações feitas no forEach e poder retornar para a view esse meu array com todos os objetos?

Li em alguns artigos que posso estar trabalhando com Closure, porém ainda não consegui gerar uma solução.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com isso, agradeço e muuuito!!

Comment: `forEach` não funciona com funções assíncronas. Provavelmente o seu problema vem daí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi solucionado?

Mesmo utilizando `async` no callback do `forEach`, o seu código só irá esperar durante o `await` internamente no callback. Ou seja, o `forEach` espera a resposta, mas o seu código não espera o `forEach`.

Geralmente para esperar a reposta de vários itens, você pode utilizar `Promise.all` ou `for await (item of itens)`, como por exemplo:

```
let membros = await model.getMembro();

// crio um array de promises, as respostas estão empacotadas dentro das promises, 
// eu tenho que esperar pela resolução das promises para desempacotar as respostas
let promisePresencas = membros.map(membro => model.getPresenca(membro.id_membro));

// este método recebe um array de promises, e retorna uma única promise
// empacotando todo o array, agora eu posso utilizar o await
let presencas = await Promise.all(promisePresencas);

let objArray = membros.map((membro, i) => ({ ...membro, presenca: gerarPresenca(presencas[i]) }));

res.render('home/index', {objArray});
```

Ou com um laço for:

```
let objArray = [];
let membros = await model.getMembro();

// mesmo processo
let promisePresencas = membros.map(membro => model.getPresenca(membro.id_membro));

let i = 0;
for await (let presenca of promisePresencas) {
    objArray.push({ ...membros[i++], presenca: gerarPresenca(presenca) });
}

res.render('home/index', {objArray});
```

Comment: Solução perfeita!

Answer (score 0):

Basta não usar forEach. Usa for (let membro of membros) {}.

Isso:

```js
membros.forEach(async membro => {
   let  presenca = await model.getPresenca(membro.id_membro);
   obj = {...membro, presenca: geraPresenca(presenca)}
   objArray = [...objArray, obj];
   //#1 console.log(objArray) retorna todo o vetor durante o loop
});
```

Por isso:

```js
for (let membro of membros) {
   let  presenca = await model.getPresenca(membro.id_membro);
   obj = {...membro, presenca: geraPresenca(presenca)}
   objArray = [...objArray, obj];
   //#1 console.log(objArray) retorna todo o vetor durante o loop
}
```

Comment: Essa sua solução também funcionou! Obrigado